# Can consuming a CosmosDB FeedIterator result in multiple continuation tokens?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

So I'm performing a query on a CosmosDB container on behalf of a client and want to support returning continuation tokens to the caller. Right now my query against CosmosDB based off the examples in the official documentation looks like:

```
FeedIterator<T> feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(queryDefinition, continuationToken, queryOptions);

// class MyResponse {
//     List<T> Objects;
//     string? ContinuationToken
// }

var myResponse = new MyResponse();

while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<T> response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    myResponse.ContinuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
    foreach (var result in response)
    {
        myResponse.Objects.add(result);
    }
}
```

So the documentation opted to use a while loop to consume the `FeedIterator`, implying it is possible this block is run multiple times and as a result we can consume more than one `FeedResponse`. Each `FeedResponse` has a `ContinuationToken` property, so it seems possible to have multiple `ContinuationTokens`. If so, is it guaranteed the latest response will have the most up to date continuation token?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; each newer continuation token is set on your response object, overwriting the previous continuation token.

I'm not sure why you have a `while` loop, though. It seems like you would just want to call `ReadNextAsync` once per request.

Comment: Code examples from Microsoft and some documentation seems to demonstrate wrapping the `feedIterator.HasMoreResults` in a while loop. See:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/Queries/Program.cs#L244

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.feediterator.readnextasync?view=azure-dotnet

Looking at the documentation for `ReadNextAsync` doesn't provide any clear reasoning why though. I could see `ReadNexyAsync` maybe mutating some internal state of the `feedIterator`? Wish the docs were more explicit.

Comment: That's probably because you *normally* iterate through all the responses. But if you're returning the continuation token to *your* caller, then your *caller* will be the one doing the `while` loop.

Comment: Ah that's a good point! All the examples I've seen wrapped in the `while` loop specify they are draining ALL the results, which isn't quite the case here for the reasons you mentioned. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It makes sense to use while loop anyway, since otherwise you may not get any results per call at all, which may be not what you want in client. Just break the loop when a suitable condition is met (i.e. when at least N results extracted -or- end of results). This way you have fewer roundtrips from client as well.